# Posting links to facebook wall from iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am posting to the facebook wall from an iPhone app. It works well when I just sends a message, but when I try to add a link the message is not posted on Facebook.

Code:

```
NSString *link = @"http://www.foo.com";
NSString *linkName = @"Bar";
NSString *linkCaption = @"Foo Bar";
NSString *linkDescription = @"Fooooooo Bar";
NSString *message = @"Message";

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId, @"api_key",
                                   message, @"message",
                                   linkName, @"name",
                                   linkDescription, @"description",
                                   link, @"link",
                                   linkCaption, @"caption",
                                   nil];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me/feed"
                      andParams: params 
                  andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                    andDelegate: self];
```

It is when I add the link and caption to the params dictionary that FaceBook will not post on the wall. I don't even get an error in `(void) request: (FBRequest *) request didFailWithError: (NSError *) error` so it seems Facebook thinks the request is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/). It's a pretty well-maintained open-source library for interfacing with the various social web services and leaves maintaining API compatibility with the ShareKit community.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted the Link in FB with the use of attachment...

```
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Visit My Site", @"name",
                            @"http://www.mysite.com", @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your Message",@"message",
                                   attachmentStr,@"attachment",nil];
```

Comment: I have seen that method used a lot and have tried it with the same result as in my first post. Also I can't find any reference to "attachment" in the documentation for the new Facebook API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

For showing links on FB, u could make use of actionLinks.

delgates as

```
dialog.actionLinks = @"[{\"text\":\"See My App here!\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php?app_id=178257532217623&ret=2/\"}]";
```

this will show ur links on right side of the post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, since everything looks fine, but this might help you troubleshoot:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Try posting your message via form on that page and see what Facebook tells you. If there is a problem, you'll see an error message.

To post a link you need to add an attachment with this syntax:

```
{ "href": "http://www.fantasy-fan.org", "name": "test", "caption": "test2", "description": "test3", "media": [{ "type": "image", "src": "http://dragontest.fantasy-fan.org/images/dwarf.jpg", "href": "http://www.fantasy-fan.org" }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FBConnect` then use this methods every thing is post on FB wall.

```
- (void)postToWall 
 {

   FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
   dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";
   dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for iPhone\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone\",\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}"];
   [dialog show];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with a PHP app and solved it by getting a page access token. Once you have a user access token go to:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

Within the returned data find the page's name and and its corresponding access token. Using the page access token allowed my links to be posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use This.This one is working fine for me.

```
 NSString *graphPath = @"me/feed";

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                self.link,@"link",
                                                self.url,@"picture",
                                                 self.message,@"name",
                                                @"Write_Captioon",@"caption",
                                                self.description,@"description",
                                                /*@"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",@"message",*/
                                                nil];

        [[FBRequestWrapper defaultManager] sendFBRequestWithGraphPath:graphPath params:params andDelegate:self];
```

Check your url too,may be that url is not of proper form.I didn't face this kind of problem in Facebook but in case LinkedIn when my url has "=",the post was not being shared,but was successfully sharing with other urls.Hope this will help you.

Comment: What is the character limit for the Parameter?